# grammar of 'sit perched on'

Tags: grammar

Is the grammar of 'perch' in the following sentence correct ?

> The tower sits perched on a stone structure.

If 'perch' is used as verb in the sentence, should it be as *sit perching*?
Could anyone please kindly help me to figure out *sit perched*.

Comment: *Perched* is a past participle here.

Comment: Either "perched" or "perching" is OK for present tense "sits".

Comment: Yes, it's OK. "Sits" is the matrix verb and the subordinate past-participial clause "perched on a stone structure" is a depictive adjunct in clause structure. Normally the non-finite is not easily omissible, but here we could simply replace it with a locative phrase like "on the top of the hill", or of course "on a stone structure"

Comment: There's a difference between the phase structure 'John sat watching the match' where the sitting and watching is cohesive (that's why John was sitting where he was), and 'On the cold bench John sat, watching the match [in a desultory fashion]' where the participle clause tacks on another piece of information. I can't find supporting evidence for this, but it seems to me that 'sits perched' is a similar phase structure with a complex verb phrase rather than a participle clause.

Comment: @HotLicks While it's grammatical, to me "perching" seems more active than "perched", so it doesn't feel as appropriate to describe an inactive object. "Batman stood perching on the tower, watching over the city".

Comment: @Barmar - Yes, there is a difference in activenessness.  "Perched" implies a static situation, which may have persisted for aeons.  "Perching" suggests a sit-uation that is somewhat more tenuous.  The latter might be appropriate if the tower appears ready to fall from the stone at any moment -- it's up to the writer to decide what image he wishes to convey.

Comment: Same structure as *The drunk man lies **covered** in his own vomit*.

Comment: @Clare - No.  There's no logical way one could claim that "The drunk man lies covering in his own vomit" is correct.  But the OP's sentence can go either way, depending on the sense to be conveyed.

Comment: @HotL I never said anything about *covering*. Thus I also wouldn't use *perching* in the original sentence.

Comment: @Clare - So you admit that your structure is not equivalent.

Comment: I admit that I have no idea what you're talking about and have zero interest in engaging with you on this subject since I disagreed yesterday   with your first unenlightened comment to this post when I glanced at it.

Answer (score -1):

To *stand on a footing* or *lie on a bed* might work but *sit on a perch* is too like *sit on a seat* or *perch on a perch*; like *record on a record*, *store in a store* or *shelve on a shelf*.

The grammar would be fine but that's less important there than the vocabulary. Combining *sit* and *perch* that way is tautological and I, or one, don't see reinforcement or emphasis as justification. It might not be as glaring as *The tower towers over…* but it will always be less smooth than jarring.

Either *The tower sits on…* or *The tower is perched on…*; possibly even, *The tower perches on…*

Does a drowning man *grasp for a grip* on… the proverbial straw? Did that straw *break a breach* in the camel's back?

Does a vulture *sit perched on*… a branch or would the bird be better to choose between *sitting* and *perching*?

Comment: 'Sit perched on' and 'sit down on' disambiguate 'sit on'.

Answer (score -1):

The problem could be the "matrix verb," or maybe just the sentence itself. In any case, stands is better than sits. "Monks from China's Shaolin Temple stand perched on tall wooden boxes." https://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/asia/why-the-kungfu-monks-are-losing-their-religion-2353184.html

Comment: If you check [Google 3-grams for 'sits perched on' & 'stands perched on'](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sits+perched+on%2Cstands+perched+on&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csits%20perched%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstands%20perched%20on%3B%2Cc0) you'll see that it appears that most people disagree with your claim that " 'stands' is better than 'sits' ". The same conclusion seems deducible from 3-grams for 'sat/stood perched on'.

Comment: Whether monks "stand perched on tall wooden boxes" or "sit perched on tall wooden boxes" depends only on whether their feet or their butts are touching the boxes. One is not better than the other grammatically. And metaphorically, in English you can describe a tower as either standing or sitting. There's no reason you have to use *stand*.